Is there a LaTeX package that will provide a brief summary description of all the packages that are included within a LaTeX project?
I was wondering if there exists a LaTeX package that will scan all of the packages that exist within a LaTeX project, then download from CTAN a brief summary description of each of the packages that are included within that LaTeX project, to then be printed out in summary format as part of the final documentation.
I realize that there are other ways to locate the brief summary descriptions, e.g.:

The "LaTeX Companion" book: It provides an extensive list of
packages with brief descriptions. Although it might not cover all
packages, it serves as a valuable resource.
Online resources: Websites such as Overleaf, LaTeX-Tutorial.com, and
Research Guides offer documentation, tutorials, and package
descriptions.
Package documentation: Many packages come with their own
documentation, often available as PDF files. You can search for the
package name followed by "documentation" to find these resources.
The texdoc command: If you have a local LaTeX installation, you can
use the command texdoc <package_name> in your terminal or command
prompt to access the documentation for a specific package.

I'm looking for a package that will automatically scan my LaTeX project, compile a list of all the LaTeX packages included within, and then download from CTAN the corresponding brief summary description of each of the LaTeX packages that are included within a LaTeX project.
I've a few hundred LaTeX packages included in my multi-year LaTeX project file, many that I've forgotten what they do. I'd be nice to have the brief description information readily available each time I typeset my project.
UPDATE 6 July 2024:
Following a suggestion from Teepeemm to use the \listfiles command to summarize a description of the LaTeX packages used in a project, I located a mature SE post by egreg at Embed nicely formatted \listfiles into document.
Within the above SE posting by egreg, focusing on the \listfiles macro that pursues A variation for separating the file date from the information:, I was able to create the following table displaying the first 10 (of ~450) LaTeX packages included in my project:

The \listfiles macro in the above SE post is outlined in sufficient detail to enable implementation of the macro within any existing LaTeX package.
Although the package descriptions can be a bit brief, the \listfiles macro in the above SE post provides the best solution I have found to date, implementing a \listfiles macro solution that is largely in line with my original request.
The one suggestion I have within egreg's \listfiles macro would be to include an option to sort the list of LaTeX packages alphabetically, to expedite tracking down a particular LaTeX package, without having to read through the full listing of LaTeX packages, that in my case consists of ~450 LaTeX packages within my project.

If you call \listfiles as the first command (even before \documentclass), then the log will contain that information at the end.  Is that sufficient?

This is something to ask from ChatGPT :)

@nplatis - I already tried.

This is mostly an idea  still in its infancy (and it will not mature) to show the CTAN description rather that the latex packages. I am afraid that the example, as is, could have a lot of issues to use with some other packages, is moreover made in Quarto and probably even some entry in the table example is wrong (sorry, no time to check), but I think that show the idea, that probably is better done manually (to deal with probably many different cases):

Select the names of packages loaded in the preambles with some tool as grep or just edit manually a copy of the preambles to make a list of the .sty names.

Obtain the list of names of the source CTAN  package with texdoc and/or tlmgr

Obtain with  tlmgr the short description of the package of these . Manually is just run tlmgr info -data name,shortdesc name1 name 2..., check for errors, and save the output in a CSV file.

With the CSV file is easy make a table with datatool (not showed, but there are many examples in another questions), or with python or R (this example).


So with a preamble like:
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

You can obtain some like this:

---
title: Styles and packages
format: pdf
engine: knitr
---

```{bash}
#| echo: false
#| include: false
#| cache: false

grep usepackage Document.tex > foo.txt
sed -i -n 's/[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}/\1\n/gp' foo.txt
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' foo.txt
sed -i 's/,/\n/g' foo.txt

echo "tlmgr info -data name,shortdesc " > CTANp.txt

awk '{ print "texdoc -l -I " $1 ".sty" }' foo.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c '{}' | sed -e 's/.*\/\(.*\)\/.*\.sty/\1/' >> CTANp.txt 

tr '\n' ' ' < CTANp.txt > CTANp.sh
echo " > foo.csv " >> CTANp.txt
chmod u+x ./CTANp.sh
./CTANp.sh

```


Sort CTAN packages with short descriptions

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| cache: false

packages <- unique(read.csv("foo.csv", header = FALSE))
names(packages) <- c("CTAN","Description")
styles <- unique(read.csv("foo.txt", header = FALSE)) 
names(styles) <- c("sty")

knitr::kable(packages[order(packages$CTAN),],row.names = F)

```

\LaTeX{} packages (`{r} nrow(styles)`): `{r} styles$sty`  

CTAN packages (`{r} nrow(packages)`): `{r} packages$CTAN`  


The CTAN Description table you created is more along the lines of what I had imagined. Thank you for the proforma. As a relative neophyte, I'll need time to implement the work/data flow by applying the above code to my LuaLaTeX project. Thank you again.

@RosesBouquet Then  easy  and  important part is that you can run  tlmgr info -data name,shortdesc forest xcolor lipsum ... ,  copy the output and edit manually to turn it into a table or a list (if you have Tex Live!). The hard part is know the true packages names. Sometimes  \usepackage{abc} does not mean that there is an "abc"  CTAN package. For instance, note that  amssymb is in the preamble, but not in table, while the contrary happen with amsfonts. This is not a mistake, it is because amssymb.sty does not have its own CTAN package and it is part of amsfonts.

When I run (Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('CTANcode.Rnw')") your code (as file: CTANcode.Rnw) using a copy of my LuaLaTeX project .tex file as Document.tex, I'm getting the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

@RosesBouquet This is a Quarto file, so it must have the extension .qmd and be compiled with Quarto. The easiest way is to open with Rstudio and push the "Render" button, but you can also run in the command line: quarto render whatever.qmd or use the quarto extension in VS Code . N.B.: Better say goodbye to Rmarkdown because is cryopreserved but mortally wounded by his creators that switch to Quarto.

OK ... after installing Quarto and Rendering your code, I get the following errors:
Quitting from lines 8-26 [unnamed-chunk-1] (CTANDescription.qmd) Error in engine(): ! sed: 1: "foo.txt": invalid command code f sed: 1: "foo.txt": invalid command code f Info: Running Texdoc not installed in the current TEXMFMAIN.
There are lots more errors. Unfortunately, after spending many hours on Rendering the above code (newbie here!), I'm not sure this is going where I would like to end up, so I'll have to stop. Thank you again for all your effort.

@RosesBouquet Note  that these commands are Unix tools running  in a bash shell. If you are using Windows this mean a virtual Machine with Linux or Linux software compiled for Windows (like Cygwin),  or simply just forget the bash part and make the lists of packages with another windows tools, or manually (the foo.csv and foo.txt are simple plain texts with just one package name per  line).

Thank you for the tip, but I'm on a Mac. With the help of my favorite AI, I was able to install and run ALL the packages needed to run R, RStudio and Quarto, all programs I have no prior knowledge of. If not for the AI, I wouldn't have known where to even start. My apologies, but your suggestion to "simply just forget the bash part" is like a foreign language. It would likely take me days to even begin to understand your first-rate suggestions, of which I am grateful. I am simply out of my league. I appreciate all that you have done. I only wish I could do justice to your contribution.

@RosesBouquet Take it easy. It took me many years to discover that all these programs  even exist, and more learn try to do something useful with all. Bash is the default shell of Linux, where you are in a terminal  with prompt to write commands, or call it inside a script  starting the script with  #!/usr/bin/bash, or in the chunk of code in Quarto with the {bash} label.  There are several shells (csh, ksh, etc.).  I never used Mac,  but probably yours is zsh.  May be echo $0 will say that (in my terminal this say just bash).

Yes, -zsh. Thank you. I have hundreds of amazing LaTeX packages in my multiyear LuaLaTeX project. Keeping it all together is a challenge and I thought it might be nice to remind myself what each package is for. As a feature (we can dream), it might be nice to have an option to see the list of the commands within each package, something that will be increasingly needed as LaTeX continues to grow. It is an amazing system, but IMHO could use a few new tools as it continues to expand. I realize here are those who'd say I've included too many packages. But my eye beholds a great beauty of a system.

@RosesBouquet. But without a doubt, the golden rule is to only use the packages you really need. Otherwise, you'll just get slow builds, package conflicts, hard-to-debug preambles, and you won't learn what each one is for. With respect the list of commands, If that was easy and useful, someone would have done it already. See that manual of tcolorbox or  biblatex  and just imagine the work of maintain as a list of commands for just  dozen package like those and what you will gain with that.

ALL great points, and ALL True! Thanks again. I only wish that I could economise on what I am loading. Having a list of 'Descriptions' for each package would have allowed me to check for candidate packages for deletion. What I was looking for were the package 'Descriptions' that are listed when you click on the 'Packages' button in the TeX Live Utility. Each Description is brief and concise, and is automatically maintained by the TeX Live Utility. Thanks again for all your code.

If you call \listfiles as the first command (even before \documentclass), then the log will contain the used files (and often a short description) toward the end.  For example:
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{document}

has a log file that contains:
 *File List*
 article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
example-image.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********


Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure why I did not try this before. The \listfiles option provides me with 2/3 of what I was looking for. Thanks again!

You can make the list of files in egreg's answer sorted alphabetically by applying \clist_sort:cn to @filelist. The only code I've added below to egreg's answer (besides a module name change) is
  \clist_sort:cn { @filelist }
    {
      \int_compare:nTF { \tex_strcmp:D { ##1 } { ##2 } > 0 }
        { \sort_return_swapped: }
        { \sort_return_same: }
    }

Here's the full example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs,yfonts}

\listfiles % initialize
\AtEndDocument{\printfilelist}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfilelist}{}
 {
  \cleardoublepage
  \section*{Used ~ packages}
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{longtable}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l l >{\raggedright}p{.6\textwidth} @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries File~name} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Date} &
    \bfseries File~info
  \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \roses_print_filelist:
  \end{longtable}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_roses_filelist_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_roses_fileinfo_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \roses_print_filelist:
 {
  \clist_sort:cn { @filelist }
    {
      \int_compare:nTF { \tex_strcmp:D { ##1 } { ##2 } > 0 }
        { \sort_return_swapped: }
        { \sort_return_same: }
    }
  \clist_map_inline:cn { @filelist }
   {
    \roses_print_fileinfo:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_roses_filelist_body_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \roses_print_fileinfo:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnT { \.(sty|cls)\Z } { #1 }
   {
    \roses_print_pkginfo:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \roses_print_pkginfo:n #1
 {
  \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_roses_fileinfo_tl { ver@#1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_roses_fileinfo_tl { & } { \& }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_roses_fileinfo_tl { ~ } { & }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_roses_filelist_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:n { #1 }
    &
    \exp_not:V \l_roses_fileinfo_tl
    \exp_not:N \tabularnewline
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}



This is basically an extension of Teepeemm's answer. It is a bash script which takes the output produced by \listfiles and creates a longtable containing the relevant TeX Live packages and their long descriptions. In general, these should match CTAN's.
It runs with sh, so it should be relatively compatible with other shells. I did not test with zsh, but I assume it has something similar i.e. a sh mode which is more-or-less POSIX compliant. However, as I say, I didn't test this.
(Further) Caveats

It is slow because tlmgr remote operations are slow. Note, in particular, that tlmgr is very, very slow if the mirror it tries to contact is problematic. Unlike most package managers, it tries and tries and tries. Moreover, it doesn't switch to another mirror even when it finally gives up. (At least, this has been my recent experience and I've not found a way to make it respond sensibly to slow or buggy mirrors.)
It makes absolutely no attempt whatsoever to work securely or to sanitise the input. Nor does it set PATH or ensure the commands it invokes are executed from the proper places. I don't know where these places are on your system, so I couldn't do even the basic things I know how to do, which are severely limited in any case.
It will mess up if any package description contains any problematic characters. To avoid this, you could comment the last two lines to block automatic compilation. Or just remove them. You probably want to tweak the formatting anyway.

To run the script, save it as e.g. pkg-parser in your project directory, cd to the directory and run
sh pkg-parser <document-name>

where <document-name> is the name of your .tex file without the extension. Hopefully there are no strange characters (e.g. spaces) in the name. The script makes an attempt to quote the name, but it is pretty minimal as safeguards go.
# pkg-parser
# try to make it a little bit safer
mkdir pkg-tbl-$$ || exit 1
# work on a copy of the log
cp "$1".log pkg-tbl-$$ || exit 1
# work only in a dedicated directory
cd pkg-tbl-$$ || exit 1
# the actual parsing
printf %b "\\\documentclass{article}\n\\\usepackage{longtable}\n\\\\begin{document}\n\\\\begin{longtable}{p{.2\\\linewidth}p{.75\\\linewidth}}\n  Package & Description " > pkg-tbl.tex || exit 1
sed -e '1,/^  *\*File List\*$/d' -e '/^  *\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*$/,$d' "$1".log > pkg-list.$$ || exit 1
sed 's/^[ \t]*\([^ \t][^ \t]*\)[ \t].*$/\1/' pkg-list.$$ > pkg-files.$$ || exit 1
(while IFS=\n read j; do tlmgr search --file "\/$j" | head -1 | sed 's/:$//' ; done < pkg-files.$$) | sort | uniq > pkg-pkgs.$$
[[ "$?" != 0 ]] && exit 1
while IFS=\n read j; do tlmgr info $j | sed -e '/^installed:/,$d' -e '/^category:/d' -e '/^shortdesc:/d' -e 's/^package:[ \t]*\([ \t].*\)$/  \\\\\n  \1 \&/' -e 's/^longdesc:[ \t]*\([^ \t].*\)$/  \1/' >> pkg-tbl.tex; done < pkg-pkgs.$$
[[ "$?" != 0 ]] && exit 1
rm pkg-list.$$ pkg-files.$$ pkg-pkgs.$$ "$1".log
printf %b "  \\\\\\\\\n\\\end{longtable}\n\\\end{document}\n" >> pkg-tbl.tex || exit 1
# you might want to comment these out and adjust the output before compiling
TEXMFHOME=. pdflatex pkg-tbl.tex
TEXMFHOME=. pdflatex pkg-tbl.tex
cd ..

# vim: ts=2:sw=2:et:nospell

The image is going to really suck due to Okular bugs on X11 and I don't know how to handle multi-page images with magick.
[Image is actually so bad I'm omitting it.]

I'm sure somebody will tell me I could do this in Lua ....

“I don't know how to handle multi-page images with magick” Try running magick montage -background white -alpha background -alpha off -density 300 -tile 1x -mode concatenate in.pdf PNG:- > out.png.

@MaxChernoff Thanks. I will try that next time. (I don't have the PDF I produced from this and, unlike most MWEs here, this one takes a while. That is, it takes a while to write the .tex file. Compilation is obviously extremely fast.) I could possibly also do this with pdftk first. But converting full pages is rather slow with magick. (Though I suppose it will be at least as slow if magick does the combining?)

Looking at this, I realise printf needs a ridiculous number of backslashes.

@cfr Re: "It is a bash script which takes the output produced by \listfiles and creates a longtable containing the relevant TeX Live packages and their long descriptions." Thank you cfr. CTAN's LONG DESCRIPTIONS is EXACTLY what I have been looking for for these past few months. I don't have time at the moment to test your code, and I believe I am running zsh,  so we shall see what happens. Thanks again!!

@RosesBouquet I did test with sh so it "shouldn't" depend on bashisms. If you have problems, let me know and I'll try it in zsh.

@cfr Thank you for your note. I'm still running with the earlier short-CTAN-descriptions solution and haven't had a chance to implement your extension of Teepeemm's answer script. The short-CTAN-descriptions code outlined above appears to be behaving well in my LuaLaTeX project. So far so good. I DO, however, want to implement your extension of Teepeemm's answer script so that I can have the longer-CTAN-descriptions solution, but I'm immersed with a short term deadline at the moment. In the meantime, can you post a sample of what your \listfiles output looks like?

@RosesBouquet If you know how to fix the Okular-on-X11 bug, I'd be happy to :-). I can convert images using magick, but larger images (e.g. a whole page) tend to be a bit much and, even with a small sample, this produces quite a lot of output. Also, I didn't really prettify it above. I figured you could format the result however you wanted and would probably want to tweak prior to compilation. Or do you mean the code results i.e. prior to compilation?

@cfr I'm looking to see what the longer CTAN LONG descriptions look like, to get an idea of what I might expect for a full listings of the > 400 LaTeX packages I use. The question I'm trying to answer is if the CTAN LONG descriptions can provide me with so much as a hint as to which package is providing what service. Right now the CTAN SHORT descriptions do NOT provide me with enough info to help me find the package I am looking for. So I don't need much of a sample. Nothing urgent as I'm tied up with another set of issues at the moment. Thanks again.

@RosesBouquet The long description is the paragraph(s) of text describing the package on its CTAN page. The short description is the title of that page (less the package name). How useful it is depends entirely on what the package's author submitted to CTAN. The information isn't prepared according to any common set of criteria, though CTAN will nudge authors to provide something if submitting these days. Just do tlmgr info <package name> for a couple of sample packages and you will get a sense of the data available.

@cfr - Thank you. I see what you mean. In many cases, the long description may not be worth the page real estate as a way to provide relevant info. If the tlmgr info <package name> command is any indication, retrieving the long description could extend my compile times significantly beyond the current half-hour for the full package. Thanks for the Terminal command.

@RosesBouquet you aren't running the retrieval as part of your compilation, are you? you really shouldn't do that. run the retrieval if you must, but store the data locally. ctan don't have the resources for people to repeatedly hit them for this kind of data every time they compile - especially since every package is a separate connection. you shouldn't do this for the short summaries either.

@cfr - Thank you for that information. I had no idea … I’ll comment out that portion of my package when I compile. As a side benefit, it may help to reduce my compile time. Thanks again!
